# Highlighting sections of HTML/code that is wrapped in <pre><code> tags

Tags: html

I am creating an online tutorial and I'm displaying the html code by wrapping it in the `<pre><code>` tags. I would like to be able to highlight certain sections of the code. Is there a way to do that when the html is wrapped in the the `<pre><code>` tags?

```
<div data-role="page">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to highlight the "page" value of the data-role attribute. I tried to surround the "page" code with a span tag and style it, but the span tag showed up in the code. I also tried to use `&lt;` and `$gt;` thinking maybe that would escape the `< >` around the span tags. It did, but it showed up in the code.

Again, I'm trying to display the code (without screenshots) with certain sections of the code highlighted with yellow.

Comment: I would use a [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) ([demoes](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/)).

Comment: Hi Jared. Important point I forgot to mention. I'm creating this page on a drupal site. I am unable to incorporate script on my own or add plugins. I am hoping that there is someway to add a tag that can be escaped from the <pre> and <code> tags. Thanks,

Comment: Then I'd try to see if you can get http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter installed.

Comment: Thanks, I will talk with the administrator and see what he can do.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape everything but the tag. I used `<mark>` since it seems more semantically correct:

```
<pre><code>&lt;div <mark>data-role=&quot;page&quot;</mark>&gt;
  &lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</code></pre>
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/MFzsS/1/

Comment: </code></pre> please, close in reversed order of opening ; ) Your tags cross and can cause unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Hello elclanrs, for some reason, the &lt; and &gt; entities are showing up on the page and not being replaced by the angle brackets. Also, with your solution, would I need to put style in the head or inline. Our system is pretty locked down and I can't put a style section in the header or link to an external stylesheet. Other recommendations? Thanks,